# How to show validation errors on form using React

Tags: reactjs, meteor

After submitting a form I'm running validation and returning an array of errors. I'm using map to break the array into a group of objects, however, I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `this.state.errors` to show the errors on the form under the right FormControl field. Any help here would be great.

`What errors look like after array is broken into`

```
Object {name: "name.first", type: "required", value: undefined}
Object {name: "name.last", type: "required", value: undefined}
```

`React component with form`

```
getValidationState() {
      var errors = this.state.errors;

      if (!$.isEmptyObject(errors))
      {
        console.log("sefsefsdf");
        errors.map(element => {
          var errors = element;
        });
      }

      if(errors) return 'error';
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <FormGroup
            validationState={this.getValidationState()} >
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              value={this.state.firstName}
              placeholder="First name"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <FormControl.Feedback />
            {this.state.errors && <HelpBlock>{this.state.errors}</HelpBlock>}

          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup >
            <FormControl
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              value={this.state.lastName}
              placeholder="Last name"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup >
            <Button type="submit">
              Save
            </Button>
          </FormGroup>
        </form>
      )
    }
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: You want to print each of the errors inside the `HelpBlock` component?

Comment: Yes. So if first name errors it show displays the error message under firstName

Comment: Okay, and this error array can contain the error it self, but must not be displayed if the value is `undefined`?

Comment: No. Value=undefined is a separate issue. If `Object {name: "name.first", type: "required", value: undefined}` then there is an error and whatever value is needs to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So unless I've misunderstood your question, you simply need to map your `errors` array. Like so:

```
{this.state.errors && 
  <HelpBlock>
    {this.state.errors.map((error, i) => <p key={i}>{error.value}</p>}
  </HelpBlock>
}
```

This will return a `<p>` tag containing the error message. You can obviously change the element to something else.

For more about this, have a look at [**Array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) over at MDN.

---

**edit:** If `errors` isn't an array initially, you'll get an error that `map` isn't a function. Make sure that the `errors` array is initialized as an array and nothing else. However, you can make an extra check in your code to assure it's an array:

```
{this.state.errors && this.state.errors.length &&
```

This doesn't only check that `errors` exists and is truthy, but that the property `length` exists as well. This will prevent errors on the common mistakes, however if `errors` for some reason is a string, the condition will be true as well. If you want a more solid solution, you could do:

```
{this.state.errors instanceof Array &&
```

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the output of `console.log(this.state.errors)`? You are most likely getting that because `errors` isn't an array. Perhaps it becomes an array later, but not on initial render?

Comment: @bp123, check my update above. Though I would double-check that your `errors` variable is *always* an array, initial render, etc.

Comment: Great, this works, however, all the errors are listed under each FormControl input field. How do you ensure that `first.name` prints the `error.value` for the `first.name` error and the `last.name` error prints the `last.name error.value`.

Comment: @bp123, I think that's another question. Please feel free to post a new one and link it to me and I'll answer it. But since your original question is answered you should mark this answer as accepted (if it helped you) and post a new question.

Comment: I'll take you up on that offer if it still stands. I posted a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/43930022/5769544). I looked for a link function but couldn't find one. This is the only way I figured I could notify you.