# Get React to display individual error messages under form input field

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-bootstrap

I'm submitting a form that returns an array of errors and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get each individual error to appear under the correct input field. Right now all the errors print under each input field.  I'm using `react-bootstrap`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
getValidationState() {
  var errors = this.state.errors;
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(errors))
  {
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
      console.log("error:", error.name);
    });
  }
}

render() {
  const inputProps = {
    value: this.state.address,
    onChange: this.onChange,
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
      <FormGroup
        validationState={this.getValidationState()} >
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          placeholder="First name"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <FormControl.Feedback />
        {this.state.errors && this.state.errors.length &&
          <HelpBlock>
            {this.state.errors.map((error, i) => <p key={i}>HEllo{error.value}</p>)}
          </HelpBlock>
        }


      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup >
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={this.state.lastName}
          placeholder="Last name"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {this.state.errors && this.state.errors.length &&
          <HelpBlock>
            {this.state.errors.map((error, i) => <p key={i}>HEllo{error.value}</p>)}
          </HelpBlock>
        }
      </FormGroup>


      <FormGroup >
        <Button type="submit">
          Save
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message for each input should be stored and displayed separately (by using state, too):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      firstNameErr: '',
      lastNameErr: '',
  }
  this.getValidationState = this.getValidationState.bind(this);
}

getValidationState() {
  var errors = this.state.errors;
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(errors))
  {
    var firstErr = '';
    var lastErr = '';
    errors.forEach((error) => {
      console.log("error:", error.name);
      // Check each error to see which input it belongs to
      // NOTE: please also consider using error.name instead, if error.message is invalid, thanks!
      if(error.message.indexOf('firstName') != -1){
        firstErr = error.message;
      }
      if(error.message.indexOf('lastName') != -1){
        lastErr = error.message
      }     

    });

    this.setState({
      firstNameErr: firstErr,
      lastNameErr: lastErr,
    });

  }
}

render() {
  const inputProps = {
    value: this.state.address,
    onChange: this.onChange,
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>

      <FormGroup
        validationState={this.getValidationState()} >
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          placeholder="First name"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <FormControl.Feedback />
        <HelpBlock>
          <p className="text-danger">{this.state.firstNameErr}</p>
        </HelpBlock>
      </FormGroup>

      <FormGroup >
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={this.state.lastName}
          placeholder="Last name"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <HelpBlock>
          <p className="text-danger">{this.state.lastNameErr}</p>
        </HelpBlock>
      </FormGroup>


      <FormGroup >
        <Button type="submit">
          Save
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    </form>
  )
}
```

That is the idea, in case it doesn't work yet, please show me here some errors in your console, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function Array.forEach `

Comment: Sorry I forgot binding the getValidationState, just added it in the constructor, could you please try again, thanks

Comment: Have just fixed : "errors.forEach((error) => {" Could you please try again

Comment: Sorry. Now there is this error. `setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144112/discussion-between-thinhvo0108-and-bp123).

Comment: this answer leads to this error:
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.